# Retrieve execution plan via XML data from sp_WhoIsActive in adhoc process

Tags: sql-server-2016, execution-plan, xml, sp-whoisactive

We have installed a process in which we execute the `sp_WhoIsActive` procedure every 1 minute. We combine some additional logic into the same job.

Currently the `sp_WhoIsActive` procedure is run every 4-5 seconds in our production environment. We are using the following code:

```
EXEC [sp_WhoIsActive] @show_sleeping_spids = 0
    ,@find_block_leaders = 1
    ,@format_output = 0
    ,@destination_table = #Temp_Session;
```

With the parameter `@get_plans = 2` the procedure `sp_WhoIsActive` code runs around 30 seconds.

We now have a new requirement for for ad hoc analysis to also retrieve the execution plan for some of queries.

My idea is to add the parameter `@get_additional_info`, which is supplied in the procedure `sp_WhoIsActive`, and then to retrieve from the `additional_info` column's XML data the value from the `<plan_handle>...</plan_handle>`.

The value(s) for the plan handles would then be stored somewhere and using a scheduled job (for example every 1 hour) retrieve the actual execution plans using `sys.dm_exec_query_plan` view.

Executing `sp_WhoIsActive` with parameter `@get_additional_info` runs almost same time as without this parameter.

#### Question

Does anybody know how to retrieve `plan_handle` from XML column which will be treated as `varbinary(64)` to use it for querying `sys.dm_exec_query_plan` view?

Comment: Do you want to collect Estimated plans or Actual plans?

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear exactly how you are storing the data you get from `sp_WhoIsActive`.

But if you have the data stored in a table then you can use the following code to get data out of the `additional_info` column, and pass ut to `sys.dm_exec_query_plan`

```sql
SELECT s.*, pl.query_plan
FROM YourSessionsTable s
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(
    CONVERT(
      varbinary(64),
      s.additional_info.value('(plan_handle/text())[1]', 'varchar(256)'),
      1
    )
  ) pl;
```

You may not get any result if the plan has already been evicted from the cache.

---

I would advise you not to use `sp_WhoIsActive` on such a frequent basis. It's very heavy, especially if you are retrieving additional information such as query plans, it's mainly designed to be used on a one-off basis when the server is under stress, to see what is going on.

Instead use XEvents and/or Query Store, which is far lighter on resources.